# How do you use selector combinators on CSS module classes that are hashed?

Tags: css

I have a CSS module where I need to override a style from a [third-party datepicker component](https://reactdatepicker.com/) that I use in my own custom component, this involves using a selector combinator to target the right element. The problem is that when I use a CSS module, the class name is now dynamically created, so the selector combination doesn't work since the class name is changed (at least I believe that's the problem?).

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/css-test-xmn6nl?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwwu8p000063b6h9t61hk6q%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwwu8p000023b6hzdnbr6ez%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwwu8p000033b6hjogy06ao%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwwu8p000053b6h1o4tgv19%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60%252C40%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqwwu8p000023b6hzdnbr6ez%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwwu8p000013b6hsr7u97aa%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwwu8p000023b6hzdnbr6ez%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqwwu8p000013b6hsr7u97aa%2522%257D%252C%2522clqwwu8p000053b6h1o4tgv19%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwwu8p000043b6htn2hxd09%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwwu8p000053b6h1o4tgv19%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqwwu8p000043b6htn2hxd09%2522%257D%252C%2522clqwwu8p000033b6hjogy06ao%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwwu8p000033b6hjogy06ao%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A21.666666666666657%257D) in codesandbox (launch the app in a new tab instead of docked on the sidebar if you're on a smaller screen).

**CSS**

```
.dateContainer {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.dateContainer .react-datepicker-wrapper {
  display: block;
}
```

**What the HTML class name ends up looking like:**
[image: Two divs with class names]

I've also tried to use an attribute selector:

```
div[class*="dateContainer"] .react-datepicker-wrapper {
 display: block;
}
```

The problem that I'm trying to solve is getting this date field to fully fill the div. When I go inspect the HTML in the browser and uncheck `display: inline-block` on the div with the `.react-datepicker-wrapper` class, it does what I want it to do.

Currently looks like this:
[image: Not filling the div]

I want it to look like this:
[image: Fully filling the div]

Comment: have you tried `!important`? I know in most cases its frowned upon, but in rare cases it is a good solution. like `.react-datepicker-wrapper{display:block !important}` ?

Comment: @imvain2 I am trying to avoid editing the default styles of react-datepicker but I have tried `div[class*="dateContainer"] .react-datepicker-wrapper {display: block !important}` before. Didn't work.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please provide the HTML and CSS as an [mre].

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, I already did. I linked the codesandbox kinda up near the top of the post.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: @Rob - I appreciate the clarification and will work on learning the embedded StackOverflow Snippets with React to replace my link.

Comment: If you actually read [the page linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by both myself and @Rob, you'll find it says so quite specifically, *in the first sentence*: "When asking a debugging question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code as *text* **in your question** that prospective answerers can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that when I use a CSS module, the class name is now dynamically created, so the selector combination doesn't work since the class name is changed (at least I believe that's the problem?).

Yes, that’s the problem, but you have the fix backwards – *your CSS* is being rewritten to target the renamed classes that would be part of your component. Indicate that your rule targets a class not scoped to your module with [`:global`](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/blob/master/docs/composition.md#exceptions):

```css
.dateContainer :global(.react-datepicker-wrapper) {
  display: block;
}
```

And even though it’s unlikely that your date container will contain any other components, it’s best practice to be specific, so use the child combinator:

```css
.dateContainer > :global(.react-datepicker-wrapper) {
  display: block;
}
```